# Full list of Codename One Components

Tags: codenameone

Sometimes it is useful to consult a list of the components offered by Codename One before making a decision on how to build a  graphical interface.  I have the following list.  Can you tell me if it is absolutely complete or if something is missing?  Thank you

```
Labels
        Label
        SpanLabel
        ScaleImageLabel
        FloatingHint
    Buttons
        Button
        SpanButton
        MultiButton
        SpanMultiButton
        ScaleImageButton
        FloatingActionButton
        ShareButton
    Toggles
        CheckBox
        RadioButton
        OnOffSwitch
        Switch
    Toggle Lists
        SwitchList
        CheckBoxList
        RadioButtonList
    Selection
        ComboBox
        Picker
    Text Fields
        TextField
        TextArea
        ClearableTextField
        AutocompleteTextField
    InputComponent
        TextComponent
        TextComponentPassword
        AutoCompleteTextComponent
        PickerComponent
    Media
        MediaPlayer
        AudioRecorderComponent
    Maps
        MapComponent
        MapContainer (Native Maps)
    Containers
        Accordion
        ComponentGroup
        InfiniteContainer
        SplitPane
        Tabs
    Dialogs/Prompts
        InteractionDialog
        Dialog
        Sheet
        ToastBar
        Progress
    Progress
        InfiniteProgress
        Slider
        SliderBridge
        CircleAnimation
        LoadingTextProgress
    Advanced
        Web View (BrowserComponent)
        SignatureComponent
        Calendar
        FileTree
        RSSReader
        ImageViewer
    Charts
        BarChart
        BubbleChart
        CombinedXYChart
        CubicLineChart
        DialChart
        DoughnutChart
        LineChart
        PieChart
        RadarChart
        RangeBarChart
        RoundChart
        ScatterChart
        TimeChart
    ToolBar
        SearchBar
        SideMenuBar
```

Comment: There's no such list, There are too many components to go through and some of these don't really make sense in a menu like list e.g. Toolbar, SearchBar, SideMenuBar etc.  Currently the best list is here: https://www.codenameone.com/javadoc/com/codename1/ui/package-summary.html It includes a short description and a picture. Ideally we'd improve that with some interactivity as well in the future.

Comment: The list in the link I provided in my reply could address the lack of a complete and documented list: I hope it will be useful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thank you for the link in the comment. I improved and integrated the previous list, and for each Component I added one or more useful links, based on my searches. Each link can lead to a javadoc, a section of the developer guide or a section of an official Codename One blog article, depending on what I found most useful.

I published this new list here:
https://www.informatica-libera.net/content/components-disponibili-codename-one
Even if the beginning of the article is in Italian, I assume there are no problems: you can ignore what I wrote in Italian and look directly at the list.

I know the ideal would be to copy this list here rather than provide a link to one of my pages, but all the links included would be laborious to recreate here.

I published it first of all for my own benefit, but I hope it will be useful for other developers as well. I accept suggestions for improvements.

Comment: very helpful effort, indeed